# Upload file using Node JS Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

UPDATE: The code below works fine as it's own "test.js" file. It only doesn't work within the context of Firebase Cloud Functions.

============================

I'm trying to upload a file to Firebase Storage from a Firebase Cloud Function. I'm testing this locally, using

```
firebase serve --only functions
```

The snippet below is just to see the issue...I'm actually calling "uploadFile" from within a Cloud Functions endpoint. Everything looks good up to the "bucket.upload(...)" line. I can echo out the options right before that line, then I get a non-descript error that it "finished with status: 'crash'".

Any ideas? This seems pretty straightforward to me!

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require("./certs/key-name.json");

firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "my-app.appspot.com"
});

var storage = firebase.storage();
var metadata = {
    id: '1234'
};
uploadFile('myFile.pdf', metadata);

function uploadFile(file, metadata) {
    var bucket = storage.bucket();
    var options = {
        destination: file,
        resumable: false,
        metadata: {
            metadata: metadata
        }
    };
    bucket.upload(file, options, function(err, remoteFile) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("Uploaded!");
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the entire code, including the https function?  Where exactly are you seeing that error?  In the output of the Firebase CLI?

Comment: bucket.upload(file, ....) want a local path to a file, so you can't just 'myfile.pdf'... you need to find its location locally.

Comment: @Doppio, [GCP Bucket Upload documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.6.x/Bucket#upload) seems to indicate you can just reference a file name. I also tried with "__dirname + '\\' + file" with no luck.